# Clients break upon libwebsockets version upgrade

Tags: http, websocket, libwebsockets

For about six months now I have been running a series of `libwebsockets` clients which connect to various services. All run relatively smoothly.

I've been running a `libwebsockets` at a git commit in the 2.x line between official releases: `afafc13`.

The following setup more or less matches the specs for the various services and works against my v2.x libwebsockets build:

```
struct lws_client_connect_info i
bzero(&i, sizeof (struct lws_client_connect_info));
i.protocol = "wss";
i.address = "ws.myservice.com
i.host = i.address;
i.port = 443;
i.path = "/";
i.ssl_connection = LCCSCF_ALLOW_SELFSIGNED;
i.protocol = protocols[0].name;
```

However when I build against the `v3.1-stable` branch of `libwebsockets`, *none* of my clients connect to its service, always citing an HTTP "upgrade" error:

```
LLL_WARN: lws_client_handshake: got bad HTTP response '400'
LLL_INFO: closing connection (prot MyClient) due to bail2 connection error: HS: ws upgrade response not 101
```

When I change the port number to 80

```
i.port = 80;
```

then *some* of my clients connect, apparently successfully "upgrading" an HTTP connection to WS. But others do not connect, and no error message is given.

In no case can I use the `3.1-stable` `libwebsockets` build to connect to a service using my existing `lws_client_connect_info` setup, and in all cases does that existing setup match the various specs as specified by the respective services.

I'm not familiar with the `WebSockets` standard and so it is of course possible that I'm missing something technical. But still it seems that I should be able to connect to a service using its given configuration and any recent `libwebsockets` build.

What am I missing?